# How to use preg_replace() to replace only specfic lines

Tags: php, regex, string

I have a table of data having same order like this

```
123.- sumi hai
bla
124.- the
secod line
is blah
125.- another line
```

And what am trying to get is something like this using php preg_replace()

```
123.- sumi hai blah
124.- the second line is blah
125.- another line
```

Pls help me
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regex like this:

```
\n^(?=[a-z])
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/pMwWrO/2)**

```
$str = '123.- sumi hai
bla
124.- the
secod line
is blah
125.- another line';

$result = preg_replace('/\n^(?=[a-z])/m', ' ', $str);

echo "The result of the substitution is ".$result;
```

Comment: Does your solution put a space after the 'hai' (line 123) or the 'the' & 'line' (line 124)? The 'working demo' does not.

Comment: @MrGlass just change the replacement string from `''` to `' '`. I've updated the answer